# Bootstrap carousel indicators not showing in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate the Bootstrap carousel into my Wordpress theme as a testimonial slider. The testimonials and logos show up (I'm using custom post types), but the only thing that doesn't show is the carousel indicators. I've looked through many Stackoverflow questions and other webpages, but I can't find a solution.

Would someone be able to take a look at my code and see if there's anything I can do to fix it? Thank you for your help.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                    'orderby'   => 'post_id',
                    'order'     => 'ASC'
                );  
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                $banner_count = 0;
                while ( $loop->have_post() ) : $loop->the_post();

                if ( $banner_count == 0 ){
                    $active_item = 'active';
                }
                else {
                    $active_item = '';
                }
            ?>
            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $banner_count; ?>" class="<?php echo $active_item; ?>"></li>
            <?php $banner_count++; endwhile; ?>
            </ol>



            <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->


            <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php 
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                $banner_count = 0;
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                if ( $banner_count == 0 ){
                    $active_item = 'active';
                }
                else {
                    $active_item = '';
                }   
            ?>
                <!-- Quote 1 -->
                <div class="item <?php echo $active_item; ?>">
                    <blockquote>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                            <img class="img-circle">
                            <?php 
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                    the_post_thumbnail( array( 200, 100 ) );
                                }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <small><?php the_title(); ?></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            <?php $banner_count++; endwhile; ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: check your css for .carousel-indicators  and .carousel-indicators li in cosole you may find why it is not displaying.

Comment: share your website URL

Comment: Hey monsty - I am trying to do the same thing as you but having issues. Are you using BS4?  If so please could you share the whole snippet of code to get this working as testimonial slider? Thank you!

Comment: Hey, there was actually just a typo in my code, as spotted by the user below. Make sure you check any mistakes in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `s` on `have_posts()` for the indicators.

```
while ( $loop->have_post() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Should be:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

I would also suggest moving your query to the top and running it once instead of twice.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'orderby'   => 'post_id',
    'order'     => 'ASC'
);  

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        . . .
        WHILE HERE FOR LIST ITEMS

    </ol>

    <?php $loop->rewind_posts(); // reset the loop and re-use ?>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        . . .
        WHILE HERE TO LOOP THROUGH ITEMS
        . . .
    </div>

    <?php
endif;
```

Comment: Wow, good spot! It works now, thank you! I had been staring at that code for so long that I hadn't noticed any errors. I'll also try your suggestion :)